# Moving average only for consecutive days in sas

Tags: sas, expand, proc

I have a question regarding moving average. I use Proc Expand (cmovave 3), but those three days can be non consecutive I suppose. I want to avoid missing data between days and use moving average for just those adjacent days.

Is there any way that I can do this? If I want to put it in another way 'how can I select a part of my data set where I have values for consecutive period (days)?'. I hope you give me some examples for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use Expand to make sure you have all the values in the timeseries interval.  Then use a data step to calculate the ma3 with the lagN() functions.

If you data already has the correct timeseries interval, then skip the PROC EXPAND step.

```
data test;
start = "01JAN2013"d;
format date date9.
       value best.;
do i=1 to 365;
    r = ranuni(1);
    value = rannor(1);
    date = intnx('weekday',start,i);
    dummy=1;
    if r > .33 then output;
end;
drop i start r;
run;

proc expand data=test out=test2 to=weekday ;
id date;
var dummy;
run;

data test(drop=dummy);
merge test2 test;
by date;
ma3 = (value + lag(value) + lag2(value))/3;
run;
```

I use the DUMMY variable so that EXPAND will convert the series to WEEKDAY.  Then drop it afterwards.